# Does $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2} + z^{2}}$ converge for $z \in \mathbb{C}-\{z = ni | n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I'm doing some review questions for complex analysis and I'm having trouble with the problem in the title.

The ratio test is inconclusive as $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}| \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$. I imagine that using the Cauchy criterion is the way to go, but I can't see how to and I also don't see how to use the fact that $z \in \mathbb{C}-\{z = ni | n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Thanks!

Comment: The fact that $z\in\mathbb C\setminus\dots$ is just to say that you never are adding a term of the form $\frac{1}{0}$, which would be problematic.  This is mostly a technical detail though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $z^2$ is just some fixed (complex) constant, so you're wondering if:
$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+z^2}$$ converges for $c\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $n^2+z^2\neq 0$ for all $n$ (this is all the condition $z\in\mathbb C\setminus\{\dots\}$ is).

Now, you may recall that:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\arctan(x) = \frac{1}{x^2+1}$$
We can apply the integral test to our sum to get that the sum converges if:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+z^2}dn<\infty$$
By standard methods, we have that the indefinite integral of this is $\frac{1}{z}\arctan(\frac{n}{z})$.
Note here that $z\neq 0$, as $0$ is $0i$, so $\frac{1}{z}$ is well-defined.

So, the integral is equal to:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{z}\arctan(\frac{x}{z})-\frac{1}{z}\arctan(0)$$
Now, $\arctan(0) = 0$, and the other term (whatever it is) is bounded by $\frac{\pi}{2z}$, which is finite.
So, the integral is finite, and the sum converges.

Comment: Thank you, I totally forgot about the integral test!

Answer (score 2):

A  simple (and more rigourous) approach: It suffices to look at abs convergence of  $\sum_{n\geq N} \frac{1}{n^2+z^2}$ for e.g. $N \geq 2\max\{|z|,1\}$. And this follows from:
$$ \sum_{n\geq N} \left|\frac{1}{n^2+z^2}\right| \leq 
\sum_{n\geq N} \frac{1}{n^2-|z^2|} \leq  \sum_{n\geq N} \frac{2}{n^2}\leq
2 \sum_{n\geq 2} \left( \frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n} \right) = 2$$

(when using an integral test, care must be taken when $z$ takes complex values)